# Parquet/Avro/CSV use case

Tags: python, hdfs, parquet, avro

We have some csv's that are in the following format

```
hash_id c1 c2 c3
```

Where `hash_id` is a `string`, `c1` `c2` and `c3` are a list of integers, 0 or 1.
Ideally, we would like to encode this as a numpy array, as we are performing some bitwise operations on these columns.
Now, we are storing the file as a `csv`, encoding the arrays as a string and using `literal_eval` to get the format back. However, this is really slow.
Also, another challenge we are facing is that the operations on this file should be scalable, so we only charge a chunk in memory. We are using a filesystem (similar to `HDFS`) to do this, where the file is mapped to several nodes.

Basically, now we are using the `csv` and reading through chunks, performing the operations and getting the results.
The operations are a search over `hash_id`, retrieving one row, and performing a bitwise operation between all the rows (`c1 xor c2 xor c3` for instance) and getting the closest to the previous retrieved row.

Are anyone of the suggested formats more suitable for this? If yes, how? We can store and retrieve the data in numpy format? Finally, any suggestions to perform the operations in chunks (ideally, at some moment the data would not fit into the memory)?